# Platform independent SSH client?

Tags: command-line, ssh, cross-platform

I am looking for an ssh client that can run from a windows terminal (cmd.exe) or a bash shell with no difference. That means that cygwin would not work (not the original cmd.exe process). This client could be written in any cross platform language (python, java, ruby).

Comment: You already checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients)?

Comment: After installing cygwin ssh you can run it from `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

[cryptzone's (was Appgate) MindTerm](http://www.cryptzone.com/products/mindterm/) SSH client may meet your needs.  It is a Java applet that can run standalone or in a web browser.

Comment: I see. It's hard to ascertain whether or not it runs in a windows command window/bash shell through CLI as it requires a license to DL. Would you happen to know if it supports that?

Comment: If you register with their site, you get one free license for MindTerm.  It runs in a separate window if started from the commandline.